Are Platform Events Only received in Top Level LWC Components
I have a child component thats subscribed to a platform event. The way it works is that in the component there are two tables , One to allow users select a file to upload to an external backend (through an Apex HTTP Callout) and another table to refresh with the files that have been sent across ( these are saved as regular records containing the file ID on the external system and no BLOB data.) The component should refresh the second table upon receiving the P.E.. When i publish the P.E from execute anonymous , it works.. but when i do the actual functionality by uploading a file , I dont see that the event is received. And it is successfully subscribed to at connectedCallBack.
import {
    subscribe,
    unsubscribe,
    
} from 'lightning/empApi';
    const EVENT_CHANNEL ='/event/ProofServe_NotificationEvent__e'


    connectedCallback(){
        subscribe(EVENT_CHANNEL, -1, this.onProofNotificationEventReceived.bind(this)).then((response) => {
            this.eventSubscription = response;
        })
    }
uploadDocumentToProof(){
        
        if(this.selectedSfFiles.length > 0){
            this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({title:'Uploading', message:'Uploading Document To Proof', variant:'info'}))
            uploadDocumentsToProof({filesToUpload : [...this.selectedSfFiles]})
            .catch(err =>{
                this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({title:'Error uploading Document', message:err.body?.message, variant:'error'}))
                console.log('errors' , err);
            })
        }else{
            this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({title:'Warning', message:'No Document Selected', variant:'warning'}))
        }
    
    }

    onProofNotificationEventReceived(event){
        console.log('Received proof notification event. Now refreshing', event);

        getAllExistingProofDocuments().then(res =>{
            console.log('proof document records', res)
            this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({title:'Refresh', message:'Files Refreshed Successfully', variant:'info'}))
            this.proofFiles = res;
        }).catch(error =>{
            this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({title:'Error Retrieving Files', message:error.body?.message, variant:'error'}))
            console.log('error retrieving ' , error)
        })
        
    }

This is the LWC code and below is the Apex snippet that does the uploading and event publishing
@AuraEnabled
    public static void uploadDocumentsToProof(List<ExistingSalesforceFileWrapperLwc> filesToUpload){
        try {

            ISobjectRepository externalDocRepository = (ISobjectRepository)ProofExtDocumentRepository.getInstance();
            List<string> messages = new List<string>();
            ProofServeIntegrationService integrationService = new ProofServeIntegrationService();
           
            for(ExistingSalesforceFileWrapperLwc wrapper : filesToUpload){
                map<string,Object> uploadResponse =  integrationService.uploadDocumentToProof(wrapper);
                string messagex = (string)uploadResponse.get('message');
                messages.add(messagex);
            }
            externalDocRepository.commitToDb();
            for(string message : messages){
                publishPlatformEvent(message, 'Proof Document Upload');
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug(e.getStackTraceString());
            System.debug(e.getMessage());
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    @future
    public static void publishPlatformEvent(string message , string type){
        List<ProofServe_NotificationEvent__e> events = new List<ProofServe_NotificationEvent__e>(); 
        events.add(new ProofServe_NotificationEvent__e(Message__c = message , Type__c='Proof Document Upload'));
        EventBus.publish(events);

    }

Id also like to note that in the Logs , I get a success that the event was published

Thanks for your question. Are you able to [edit] it and provide the code within your LWC that handles the subscription as well? Also just to clarify, when your publish the PE via the execute anonymous, is the second table being refreshed?

@CallumMacErlich , Im sorry it took this long..  Yes the second table refreshes when i publish in execute anonymous. The way I know that is happening is because i publish a showToast event in the same block of code that works
